# How can I install Gnome Desktop(Wayland) while using ubuntu-base build my ubuntu20.04?

Tags: apt, gnome, xorg, wayland

My Steps:

1.To start with, download the ubuntu-base-20.04.1-base-arm64.tar.gz from ubuntu-cdimage. PS: device platform is aarch64.

2.Extract the contents of the tar file using the command tar -xf , and then mount the host directories: /proc, /sys, /dev, and /dev/pts. After that, chroot into the system using qemu-aarch64-static.

3.Run the following commands:

apt update && apt install sudo language-pack-en-base ssh net-tools ethtool ifupdown iputils-ping htop vim kmod network-manager openbox make xorg xwayland weston
apt install ubuntu-desktop

4.Create a new user using the command adduser xxx, and then exit.

5.Build the flash.img file and flash it to my aarch64 platform device.

6.Resize the filesystem using the command resize2fs mmcblk0p3.

Question:

I'm facing an issue where Wayland Gnome is not working during system boot. I can only log in with X11. I have already tried editing /etc/gdm3/custom.conf, commenting out /lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules, and running the command gnome-shell --wayland. However, none of these solutions have worked. Whenever I try to log in using Wayland, I either get a black or purple screen, or I am redirected to the X11 login.

If you have any solutions or suggestions, please help me out. Thank you!